# Generating unsigned RSA Public Key with openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key

Following code is simplified to demonstrate plain RSA public key with the OpenSSL library:

```
RSA_ptr rsa(RSA_new(), ::RSA_free);
BN_ptr bn(BN_new(), ::BN_free);
BN_set_word(bn.get(), RSA_F4);  //65535
RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa.get(), 320, bn.get(), NULL);
BIO * keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
i2d_RSAPublicKey_bio(keybio, rsa.get());
char buffer2 [2048];
size_t pubKeyBufferSize = BIO_read (keybio, buffer2, 320);
std::cout << Convert::BinToHexString(buffer2, pubKeyBufferSize); //using here our internal routine to print binary data
```

Output from this will come up with binary data in DER ANS.1 format like this:

```
30 ;SEQUENCE
  30 02 29 ;SEQUENCE + size
    00 ;leading zero of INTEGER
    CCEE6526AE9D4380B670A23F55B840F8C5D8CC784E06E123C126753525FDFE1949...
  02 03 ;SEQUENCE + size
    010001
```

Now, the "leading zero of INTEGER" part is present to indicate that following value is positive value integer. However I need to get rid of it due to some legacy reasons.

I was going through openssl source and found that through the DER construction its presence is decided based on ASN1_VALUE->type & V_ASN1_NEG, but I am unable to track down where to set generated PublicKey as V_ASN1_NEG (or influence it to be generated as negative).

Other way to handle this is to write my own TLV-DER parser and re-pack these few bytes to comply with what I need, but I would rather enforce API to do that for me, if it makes sense.

Would you have any advice on this?

Comment: You can't. RSA is defined for a modulus which is the product of (usually two) primes and thus positive; a negative modulus doesn't work. The encoding you want is invalid, and OpenSSL won't do it; do your own.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you Dave